# Exporting list to Excel

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, export

Can I export a list into Excel (or some other format) in Sharepoint 2013? Is this feature available out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and I am pretty sure it's available in earlier version of SharePoint too. Follow steps below,

[image]

[Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/export-a-sharepoint-list-to-a-spreadsheet-HA001119639.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, on the ribbon (when viewing the list), select List > Export to Excel.